# Electron Printing on Windows doesn't work

Tags: node.js, pdf, printing, electron

I'm working on a Kiosk App and i use my Macbook to do it, but, the soft will run on Windows, so, i did everything on my macbook, and everything works fine, but, when i was on the windows machine and build the release for windows, it doesn't print, and don't show any error, so idk how to debug it.

I'm using the Printer Api included in Electron, and like i said, **in osx it works** !, i'm doing this:

```
var window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
window.webContents.print({
    silent:true
});
```

The thing is, if i use the print with `silent:false` and i select some printer it send the task, but it's never printed (i can saw just for a sec the print queue but it disappear immediately). So, i tried to do a `printToPDF()` and it works, it saves the PDF, i can see it.

I tried to send the task to a "PDFGenerator printer" and it generates a PDF but, it says that it's "not a pdf or corrupt"

I'm using:

- electron-prebuilt: 0.37.2
- node: 4.4.2

I hope this make sense to anyone.

**UPDATE**

I found the problem, in this versión of electron this doesn't include the "pdf.dll" so you have to copy it or downgrade to some 0.36.x [here the source](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4906)